# How to read specific lines of a txt file and display to JTable

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jtable, filereader

I'm trying to display the txt file into my `JTable`. The purpose is to show the usernames and the account type. I have set a `JComboBox` that has the choices `Admins` and `Cashiers`.

The txt file is used for the log in screen, and it is stored in a txt file. This is for a school project only.

Content of txt file of `admin.txt`:

```
Username:admin
Password:password
Type:admin

Username:admin2
Password:password2
Type:admin
```

Output:

[image]

This is the code:

```
 String filePath = "C:\\Users\\zagad\\IdeaProjects\\DATABYTES\\login\\admin.txt";
                File file = new File(filePath);
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) userTable.getModel();
                    Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                        String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
                        String[] dataRow = line.trim().split(" ");
                        model.addRow(dataRow);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

What I want is to hide the text "`Username: , Password: and Type:`". I just want to show the username on the left and the account type on the right, which is admin.

I am not sure on how to code to split it and display them to their following `JTable` cells.
And, the user will be adding more accounts, so the list will be longer, with the same format.

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Expected output:

[image]

After trying the code:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the data in your file.

One way might be to create a `HashMap` of each pair of data.

Then as your read each line in the file you would:

1. split the data into two fields
2. add the data to the HashMap
3. when you have 3 items in the HashMap it is now time to add the data to the TableModel. Then you clear the HashMap.

So the basic structure might be something like:

```
HashMap<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();

//for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) // don't make assumptions about the size
for (int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++) 
{
    String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
    String[] dataRow = line.trim().split(" "); // why are you splitting on " "???
    userInfo.put(dataRow[0], dataRow[1]);

    if (userInfo.size() == 3)
    {
        Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
        row.add( userInfo.get("Username") );
        row.add( userInfo.get("Type") );
        model.addRow( row );
        userInfo.clear();
    }
}
```

Of course this solution assumes that the data is always in the correct format. You would also need error checking code for the blank line since the `split(…)` method will not return any data.

Comment: Hello! Sorry, I didn't notice the `split`. What should I do as I must change it and now get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: I tried changing the regex to `":"`, and it now it separates the text `Username` and the username `admin` itself. (pic above)

Comment: Do some basic debugging (I can't guess what your actual code looks like). I gave you the basic idea. Do you understand the concept? You should only ever add two rows of data to the table. Why do you have 4 rows? It seems like you don't understand the concept of using the HashMap. If the code is implemented properly you should add 3 key/value pairs to the HashMap, then you add 1 row of data to the model and then clear the HashMap. Don't blindly copy code unless you understand the intent of the code.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it out! I forgot to reply yesterday that I solved it. I'm new into everything Java related. Again, thank you so much.